# LibreOffice upper case

Tags: libreoffice

I using the Libre Office, but all what I typing transforms to the upper case. How I can suppress this ? I already try to find solution in Google, but has no results.

Comment: Have you checked that this is NOT a text attribute, within the LibreOffice document? eg. (within document) **right-click > character > font-effects > Effects (drop down)** is set to **Capitals**